# Delete object from array in mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I have a mongoose Schmea, which looks like this: (Simplified)

```
const refreshSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    token: String,
    expiration: Date
})

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: String,
    refreshTokens: [refreshSchema],
})
```

I have added some objects to the array refreshTokens, now I am trying to delete some of them

```
await User.update({email: this.email}, {$pull: { token }})
await User.updateOne({email: this.email}, {$pullAll: [{ token }]})
```

Neither works, the object still exists in refreshTokens. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the value of `token`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form of [$pull](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) operator is:

> { $pull: { <field1>: <value|condition>, <field2>: <value|condition>, ... } }

So your query should be:

```
await User.update({email: this.email}, {$pull: { refreshTokens: { token } }})
```